# Not able to post on facebook wall in every one minute

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am developing one android application , in that application i want to post message on facebook in every 1 minute.

There is no problem in my code . In Every one minute i call the following method and it call successfully everytime , but in facebook i am not able to see all the post, facebook can only show the post after **every ten minutes.**

Code .

```
public void postOnWall(String msg) 
    {
        try 
         {
            if(mFacebook != null)
            {
                String response = mFacebook.request("me");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", msg);
                parameters.putString("description", "");
                response = Profile.mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) 
                {
                       Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                }
            }
         } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can you tell me what is the exact problem , why i can't see all the post on wall ? I can only see the post of every 10 Min.

Comment: Perhaps your calculation on the interval on which to post is not correct, can you post it here? If it is, Facebook may restrict API-calls to once every ten minutes to prevent spam.

Comment: Facebook may prevent spamming by disabling the post via api every 10 mins, check the developer docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android

Comment: @LalithB Thanks Lalith for your quick response but your link is broken.

Comment: @Ruben Thanks Rubin for your response .

Comment: @ChiragRaval http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/#step2 The link for AdditionInfo doesnt work for me either. :P guess its a broken link at Facebook.FYI Even twitter doesnt allow posting every 10 secs through API.